# angular md-dialog using controller scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, mddialog

I open a dialog with mdDialog when checking a checkbox (in the example checkbox 1).
Within this dialog there are several input fields, which should be connected via ng-modell to a controller - but it seems, that is not the scope used by the main controller (in the example myCtrl).

How can I use the same scope in the dialog and myCtrl? I tried locals to access the parent scope, but this didn't work.

Here is the plunker:

```
[https://plnkr.co/edit/9biRK5oskpQRhRWyeHWd](https://plnkr.co/edit/9biRK5oskpQRhRWyeHWd)
```

Answer (score 2):

just pass the `$scope` to `$mdDialog.show`

```
$mdDialog.show({
    scope: $scope,
    controller: function () {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: great! That did it!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the loacals. It can use myCtrls scope.

```
<md-radio-group ng-model="dialog_radio1">
```

Then in the cancel function I was able to log the selected radio value from myCtrls' scope.

```
$scope.cancel = function () {
                        $mdDialog.cancel();
                        console.log($scope.dialog_radio1);
                        };
```